# Having a problem binding an event handler in this way whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind an event handler using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var newsScrollerForPage = new NewsScroller();
            newsScrollerForPage.init();

           $('#scroller-left-a').bind('onclick', newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage());

});


<div class="scroller-left">
        <a id="scroller-left-a" href="#">
            <img src="/Images/Left-Scroller.jpg"/>
        </a>
</div>
```

But I'm having a problem:

> handler is undefined [Break On This
>   Error] if ( !handler.guid ) {

Is there anything wrong with the way I am trying to bind this event handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing in this line:

```
$('#scroller-left-a').bind('onclick', newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage());
```

...is *calling* your function, and passing its return value into `bind`. (You're also using the wrong name for the event.)

Instead:

```
$('#scroller-left-a').bind('click', $.proxy(newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage, newsScrollerForPage));
```

Three changes there:

1. Using "click", not "onclick".
2. Don't *call* your function, *refer to* it.
3. Because I'm assuming that you want `this` within your `decreasePage` to refer to `newsScrollerForPage`, I'm using [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to ask jQuery to make that happen for us. `$.proxy` accepts a function reference (`newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage`, note there are no `()` after that) and a *context* (`newsScrollerForPage`) and returns a new function that, when called, will call that function and set the context (`this` value) during the call to the context provided.

Alternately, instead of `$.proxy` you can just use a closure directly:

```
$('#scroller-left-a').bind('click', function() {
    newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage();
});
```

That works because the anonymous function is a closure over the `newsScrollerForPage` symbol. But the advantage to `$.proxy` (other than the fact its arguments are backward, IMHO) is that if the scope you're doing this in has a lot of data you don't want closed over, it creates a more contained closure for you. (If that didn't make sense, my article [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) may help.)

Comment: @Felix: Yes, I put them in the order God intended instead of the *completely and utterly wrong* order jQuery wants them. ;-) Only remembered when I went to link the docs. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: You beat me to it with a much better answer than the one I was just writing. I'm glad I didn't hit save reply. :) Have a +1 on me.

Comment: :) While all you say is true, I don't think the error comes from the handler binding... binding `onclick` does not work, so the error must come from the initialization... *Edit:* oh wait... does bind throw an error if you pass `undefined`?

Comment: @Felix: I don't think I follow. There are three distinct issues in the code, not just the context thing. *Edit*: Oddly, in my tests, no, `bind` doesn't throw an error when I pass it `undefined`. But my suspicion is that if @Pete2k fixes these three things, either the problem will get fixed, or at least more information will become avaiable. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Well, I was thinking where the error comes from... because I never heard that jQuery throws an error if you pass an `undefined` handler to `bind`, so I thought the error might come from `new NewsScroller()` or `newsScrollerForPage.init();`. At least in the latest version, this code would not throw this error: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L28 But as you can also see, this is some bug fix... maybe the OP is using an older version, then the error would occur in https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L41

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, I tested it too. :-) Still worth fixing, but it may not be the complete answer.

Comment: So yes, passing the correct handler most likely fixes the problem (unless he does something similar in the two other function calls).